# Why does my array methods function return nothing when I try to get an individual item's property?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, rtk-query

I am struggling to find a way to implement a voting functionality for my Reddit clone.

I am using rkt-query to mutate the Firebase database and rtk to manage my state.

However, I am having difficulty accessing individual items with .find function. So instead of initiating only one instance of the vote object on the database, many new instances of the object are being created over and over again.

```
const handleVote = async(event: React.MouseEvent<HTMLButtonElement, MouseEvent>, post: PostType, value: number) => {
    
    event.stopPropagation(); 
   // Step 1: Check if the user is logged in. If not, open the auth modal and return.
    if (!user) {
        dispatch(openAuthModal('login'));
        return;
    }; 
    // Step 2: Get the user id from the user object.

    const { uid } = user;
    
   try {

    // Step 3: Find the vote record for the post. Error: I cannot get to postId on each item. 
    const voteRecord = votes.find(vote => vote.postId === post.id);

    // Step 4: If there is no vote record, create a new vote and dispatch it to setVotes
    if (!voteRecord) {
        console.log('no vote record')
        const newVote: Vote = {
            postId: post.id!,
            value,
            communityName: community.name,
        }
        castVote({ uid, value, newVote });
        dispatch(setVotes([...votes, newVote]));
    }

    // Step 5: If there is a vote record and its value is different from the current value, update it and dispatch it to setVotes.
    if (voteRecord && voteRecord.value !== value) {
        console.log('vote record exists')
        console.log({ 'record': voteRecord })
        const updatedVote: Vote = {
            postId: post.id!,
            value,
            communityName: community.name,
        }
        updateVote({ uid, value, updatedVote });
        dispatch(setVotes(votes.map(vote => vote.postId === post.id ? updatedVote : vote)));
    }
    // Step 6: If there is a vote record and its value is same as the current value, update it and dispatch it to setVotes.
    if (voteRecord && voteRecord.value === value) {
        const updatedVote: Vote = {
            postId: post.id!,
            value,
            communityName: community.name,
        }
        updateVote({ uid, value, updatedVote });
        dispatch(setVotes(votes.map(vote => vote.postId === post.id ? updatedVote : vote)));
    }

   } catch (error: any) {
          console.log(error);   
   }
}
```

please see my types, and data structure

```
export interface Vote {
id?: string;
postId: string;
value: number;
communityName: string;
```

};

```
export interface PostsState {
post: Post | null;
posts: Post[];
votes: Vote[];
```

};

Just in case someone feels like helping further. See rkt-query endpoints

```
castVote: builder.mutation({
        queryFn: async( { uid, value, newVote }: {uid: string, value: number, newVote: Vote} ) => {

            try {
                const batch = writeBatch(firestore);

                const voteRef = doc(collection(firestore, 'users', `${uid}/votes`));
                const postRef = doc(firestore, 'posts', newVote.postId);
                
                batch.set(voteRef, { ...newVote, id: voteRef.id });
                batch.update(postRef, { numberOfUpvotes: increment(value) });
                await batch.commit();

                return { data: { voteRef } };


            } catch (error: any) {
                return { error: error.message };
            }
        },
        invalidatesTags: ['Vote']
    }),
    updateVote: builder.mutation({
        queryFn: async( { uid, value, updatedVote }: {uid: string, value: number, updatedVote: Vote} ) => {

            try {
                const batch = writeBatch(firestore);
                const voteRef = doc(firestore, 'users', `${uid}/votes/${vote.id}`);
                const postRef = doc(firestore, 'posts', updatedVote.postId);

                if (value === updatedVote.value) {
                    batch.delete(voteRef);
                    batch.update(postRef, { numberOfUpvotes: increment(value * -1) });
                }

                if (value !== updatedVote.value) {
                    batch.update(voteRef, { value });
                    batch.update(postRef, { numberOfUpvotes: increment(value * 2) });
                }

                await batch.commit();

                return { data: { voteRef } };
            } catch (error: any) {
                return { error: error.message };
            }
        }, invalidatesTags: ['Vote']
    }),
```

Comment: NB: [sudo](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sudo)code isn't the same as [pseudocode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pseudocode)